# Get the value of differents attributes with localStorage.getItem()?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, data-retrieval

I am trying to create a little app, and I need to store some data.
I store them like this :

```
localStorage.setItem(taskID, taskTitle, taskTotal, taskActual, taskProgress);
```

(the `taskID` `taskTitle`, etc.. are values that I get from a form)

So this actually works well, and I have only one problem :
I can easily retrieve the `taskID` using:

```
for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var taskID = "task-" + i;
};
```

but how can I retrieve the other values? Like if I want to retrieve `taskActual` value, how can I easily do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how it works. Your code sets the value `taskTitle` under key `taskID`, the rest of arguments is discarded. Then you can only retrieve the `taskTitle` using `localStorage.getItem( taskID )`.

If you want to store more attributes you need to either store multiple items, for example:

```
var taskID = 'task-1';
localStorage.setItem(taskID +'-title', taskTitle);
localStorage.setItem(taskID +'-total', taskTotal);
// etc
// to retrieve:
var title = localStorage.getItem('task-1-title');
```

or store a serialized JSON:

```
var taskId = 'task-1', taskData = { title : 'task title', total : 'task total' /* etc.. */ };
// store
localStorage.setItem(taskID, JSON.stringify( taskData ) );
// retrieve
var task = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('task-1') );
// now you can use task.title, task.total etc
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try that ! :)

Comment: Hello, 
I had the time to make the changes in my code including the first code you show and it work great !
Thank you again ! :)

Answer (score 0):

in local storage you are saving a key and a value. In this instance your 'keys' are the named items, i.e TaskId, taskTitle, etc. You need to have a corresponding value associated with the key. For example: localStorage.setItem('taskId',1); In this example, should you call localStorage.getItem('taskId'), the result would be 1, as it is it's corresponding value.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that we can add more that one value to a key.
thank you for your answer !